# Перед каждым встает вопрос: "<текст>". Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужны ли кавычки в этом предложении:

**Перед каждым встает вопрос: "текст текст".**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки не нужны, сообщение можно оформить в виде БСП.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Двоеточие  в БСП ставится,  если второе предложение поясняет какие-либо слова в первом предложении, например:

Мы с удивлением спрашивали (о чем?): неужели Сильвио не будет драться?

Можно перефразировать: Мы с удивлением задавали себе вопрос (какой?): неужели Сильвио не будет драться?

Comment: @София, Вы, кажется, ошиблись с местоположением вопросительного знака, которым увенчано предложение *Мы с удивлением спрашивали (о чем?): неужели Сильвио не будет драться*. Как бы это не стало для кого пищей для мучительных размышлений... Поменяйте местами закрывающую кавычку и вопрос, если Вам не трудно.

Answer (score 1):

Что за вопрос: текст, текст? Совершенно корявая же фраза.

Comment: А чем она корявая? Например:
Перед каждым копирайтером встает вопрос: нужно ли ставить кавычки.

Comment: Это не ответ. Для "уточнений и указаний на проблемы в сообщении" используются комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки *возможны*. Тогда это будет прямая речь. Но без них можно и обойтись. Тогда это будет бессоюзное сложное предложение.

*Перед каждым встаёт вопрос: "Почему это обязательно прямая речь?"*

*Перед каждым встаёт вопрос: почему это обязательно прямая речь?*

Comment: Все же это скорее описание вопроса, чем прямая речь (пусть даже внутреннняя).

Comment: @М_Г и как же разграничить описание вопроса и прямую речь? Одна из функций прямой речи - это выражать _мысли_. Можно спокойно заменить на:

_"Почему это обязательно прямая речь?" - думает каждый._

И смотрите: всё отлично получается! Нельзя ведь задаваться вопросом, при этом не думая о нём.